# Importing from SolidWorks and then using subdivision in blender

Tags: export, import, subdivision-surface

When I try to do this with an object that I've made in solidworks the mesh looks absolutely terrible, spikes, jagged edges etc. You know the deal.
I have tried doings "Tris to quads" and "Limited dissolve" with various values in order to fix this mesh. However neither of those methods has worked for me.

I have tried exporting the SolidWorks model in both .wrl format and .STL format, neither of which has looked good when I use the subdivision modifier, I have also looked for a way to export the model using quads instead of SolidWork's seemingly standard setting of exporting in Triangles.

Basically my question is:

How do I modify my export settings or change my mesh in such a way that subdivision surface is possible without ruining the mesh.

OR

If there is any way to make SolidWorks export in quads exclusively

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Solid Works

Comment: If you want to use Subdivision you need carefully planned [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com), no amount of export settings will fix CAD models

Answer (score 2):

Having worked quite a bit with SolidWorks models myself, I understand your pain. There isn't a single quick fix, but there are some things I have learned that have helped me mitigate the poor topology.

The first thing you should do is merge triangle pairs into quads: In **Edit Mode**, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

Next, turn on Smooth Shading and Auto Smooth:

[image]

I have found these two will often smooth out the appearance enough that I don't need further subdivision.

In the case of the model I used as an example, though, I spent hours and hours reworking the topology in Edit mode to get it to the quality I wanted. As @Duarte said in the comments, the best thing is just to have good topology, which SolidWorks doesn't provide.