# Disconnected parts of meshes and bizarre pointiness behavior from imported geometry

Tags: mesh

Using imported geometry from Solidworks (where I do most of my modeling), I run into issues when modifying those meshes or applying image textures. You can see below that the pointiness data is all messed up and that parts of the mesh come apart when I apply a solidify modifier. I've tried various methods of cleaning up the mesh (including merge by distance, which creates the weird shadow artifacts shown in the third image) to no avail. If anyone has some insight into what's causing these problems or how I might fix any of them it would be greatly appreciated!

[image: pointiness artifacts]

[image: disconnected mesh parts using solidify]

[image: mesh after merge by distance]

Comment: I guess your geometry is bad and you'd have to clean it up in the first place. Solidworks trying its best converting the model into polygons but there is some manual cleanup required, always. Recommend share a blend file of any sample geometry so we can have a look.

Comment: Related: [Any tips for simplifying CAD models?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/75263/31447) or [Importing from SolidWorks and then using subdivision in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127331/31447)...

Comment: Thanks, I'm new so unsure if there's a proper way to share .blends, but here's a link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7ih2wpdfu61bnu/export%20test.blend?dl=0

I have had a little success with a remesh modifier, but obviously that's not ideal

Comment: @StoweHammarberg Dropbox is acceptable. blend-exchange.com is the completely official file sharer for blender stackexchange, while pasteall.org/blend has been sometimes used, I think because it allows for larger files.

Comment: As expected: It's a mess :) Don't have the time right now but converting tris to quads, removing all duplicated vertices *(Merge by Distance)* and removing custom split normals is some sort of improvement already, which should make it "renderable" and allows to use the pointiness attribute. If you want a prefect model, you'd have to retopo the object using quads only, see: http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/ReTopologyModeling, https://topologyguides.com/